# PYSPARK:- Exploding the array in dataframe without loosing null values:'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Getting error while calling below code.This is exploding the array in dataframe without loosing null values but while calling columns I am getting error saying 
object has no attribute '_get_object_id'. Need help in other way of calling column that can work.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from functools import reduce

    def explode_outer(df, columns_to_explode):
        array_fields = dict([(field.name, field.dataType)
                             for field in df.schema.fields
                             if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType])

        return reduce(lambda df_with_explode, column:
                      df_with_explode.withColumn(column, explode(
                          when(size(df_with_explode[column]) != 0, df_with_explode[column])
                              .otherwise(array(lit(None).cast(array_fields[column].elementType))))),
                      columns_to_explode, df)
```

When doing :

```
cols = ['columname']
df_1 = df.select(explode_outer(df,cols))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Comment: is it the real code or you adapted ? The error comes from this code or the original one ?

Comment: this is thr original code from which error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Its done as there is Key error while fetching the column from nested data. After handling that code is working fine....Updating Question also for proper use for others.
Thanks